# how to give Page View Controller a "Cover Vertical" transition style

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, ios-animations

With a Navigation View Controller, I can give a "Cover Vertical" transition style animation. However, having trouble replicating that with a Page View Controller. The only options given in the story board are "Scroll" and "Page Curl". Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Why not using an UINavigationController if it does what you want ? UIPageViewController is not very customizable.

Comment: hoping to do it with page view controller so I don't have to create a custom page control indicator (the page dots on the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

It looks a little bit tricky but it should work :

Create a UIViewController which will be a Container Controller. Add a UIPageControl where ever you want. Then programmatically add a UINavigationViewController as a child of the container and add its view to the view hierarchy. You can use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: of the main storyboard and don't forget to set constraints to it if you're using AutoLayout. Use a delegate between the container and the UINavigationViewController or the parentViewController property of the UINavigationViewController to change UIPageControl when the user navigates in the UINavigationViewController.

UIPageViewController is good to do only one single thing. Most of the time I prefer using a custom container controller rather than using it.